# Regarding dictionary value manipulation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, dictionary, logic

CONTEXT:
The code is to be used for representing graphs for use in implementations of graph search algorithms (like Breadth-First Search).
I want to store the graph in form of a dictionary, where keys represent the nodes and each key has three corresponding values. First is a set of nodes with which the "key" shares an edge. Second is a Boolean flag for showing visited/not visited. Third is distance of the "key" from starting node.

```
"""
The 'test.txt' file contains the following:

1   2   3   4   5
2   1   3   4   5
3   1   2   5
4   1   2
5   1   2   3
"""

import math as m

def readGraph(path):
    a = {}
    file = open(path)
    data = file.readlines()

    for line in data:
        items = line.split()
        items = [int(i) for i in items]
        a[items[0]] = items[1:len(items) + 1], 0, m.inf

    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    G = readGraph('test.txt')
    print(G)
```

The dictionary (stored in 'G') for the given file is: 
`G = {1: ([2, 3, 4, 5], 0, inf), 2: ([1, 3, 4, 5], 0, inf), 3: ([1, 2, 5], 0, inf), 4: ([1, 2], 0, inf), 5: ([1, 2, 3], 0, inf)}`

DOUBT:
Suppose now I want to change the second value of key 1, from 0 to 1.
Typing `G[1] = G[1][0], 1, G[1][2]` does not seem efficient.
Is there a better approach?

UPDATE:
I tried saving the dictionary entries as lists, but that is undesirable as it would change the format of dictionary, which I want to implement.

The following is a solution, but still I want to use the dictionary in its default form, with the elements of each key stored as tuple.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    G = readGraph('test.txt')
    print(G)
    G[1] = list(G[1])
    G[1][1] = 1
    print(G)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the values for each node as a list instead of a tuple:

```py
a[items[0]] = [items[1:len(items) + 1], 0, m.inf]
```

and then just update the value you want directly:

```py
G[1][1] = 1
```

Another option (thanks to [Bilal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8140836/bilal-zaib) for his suggestion of this approach) is nested dictionaries:

```py
a[items[0]] = {"edges": items[1:len(items) + 1], "is_visited": 0, "dist": m.inf}
```

Then you could access the individual elements as:

```py
G[1]["is_visited"] = 1
```

Comment: Yes. I have done the implementation that way already. I want to try it out using dictionaries.

Comment: You are currently storing the values as a tuple

Comment: Yes. G[1] = list(G[1]) and then G[1][1] = 1 also works. I tried storing the dictionary entries as lists but then that would be way to similar too the lists implementation. Cant I access the value using the default format of the dictionary?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What exactly are you looking for and what do you mean by a more efficient implementation?

Comment: I want to edit the values with the elements stored in form of tuple

Comment: A tuple is an immutable data structure in python, which basically means after initialization, you cannot update the individual elements of a tuple https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: No problem! I have updated my answer to list both options

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this, you can use nested dictionary to store the node. Here is how graph `G` will look like.

```
G = {
    1: {
        'nodes': [2, 3, 4, 5],
        'is_visited': 0,
        'distance': 'inf'
    },
    2: {
        'nodes': [1, 3, 4, 5],
        'is_visited': 0,
        'distance': 'inf'
    }
}
```

and then you can get values by indexing.

```
G[1]['is_visited'] = 1
```